# Opening RSS page errors with “This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it.”

Tags: xml, rss

I have BuddyPress on my website, and when I'm trying to go the link RSS, the result is this:

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/" xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>SmartCrow | Activités du site</title>
        <link>http://smartcrow.pe.hu/activites-du-site/</link>
        <atom:link href="http://smartcrow.pe.hu/activites-du-site/feed/" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
        <description>Fil d'activité de tout le site</description>
        <lastBuildDate>Tue, 25 Apr 2017 17:32:58 +0000</lastBuildDate>
        <generator>https://buddypress.org/?v=2.8.2</generator>
        <language>fr-FR</language>
        <ttl>30</ttl>
        <sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>
        <sy:updateFrequency>2</sy:updateFrequency>
        <item>
            <guid isPermaLink="false">2fae35002159291b18f0446066133f9f</guid>
            <title>admin a publié une note: j</title>
            <link>http://smartcrow.pe.hu/activites-du-site/p/3/</link>
            <pubDate>Tue, 25 Apr 2017 17:28:05 +0000</pubDate>
            <content:encoded><![CDATA[<p>j</p>]]></content:encoded>
            <slash:comments>0</slash:comments>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

That message says the XML doesn't haves any style to present it in a better way than a simple xml.
This style can be a simple css like the css you use to style yout html webpages.

You should add this code to the header of the RSS file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="http://your.site/rss.css" ?>
```

And create an external css file with the filename which the xml-stylesheet tag previously added to your RSS will call.

```
rss {
    display: block;
    font-family: verdana, arial;
}
title {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 2px;
    color: gray;
    border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}
link {
    display: block;
    font-size: small;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
item {
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 30px 2px 30px;
}
docs {
    display: block;
    background-color: #ffffe6;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #7f7f7f;
    border: 1px solid silver;
}
/* all hidden elements */
language, lastBuildDate, ttl, guid, category, description, pubDate {
    display: none;
}
```

Feel free to modify the css ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Re root system cat logs and  start KAI 12 to run a new firewall from a built-in 1 with the program its running then when completed just use troubleshooting to configure all system networks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).